# How to send Query parametars from activity in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

I have following service for retrieving transaction list from server:

```
@GET("/api/UserPurchaseReports")
Call<List<Transactions>>getTransactions(
        @Query("mounthNumber")int month,
        @Query("yearNumber")int year
);
```

and I call it from here NetworkSDK.java

```
  public void getTransactions(Callback<List<Transactions>>callback){
  Call<List<Transactions>>call =     
  BaseClient.getService().getTransactions(4,2016);
  call.enqueue(callback);
}
```

As you can see I am sending 2 params (month is 4 and year is 2016 both are integers)

Now I have a fragment which show list for the date that user choose but I got no idea how can i send that params from fragment this is the code :

```
    public void showList(){
    NetworkSDK.getInstance().getTransactions(new     
    Callback<List<Transactions>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Transactions>> call, 
        Response<List<Transactions>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccess()){
                Log.d("Data", String.valueOf(response.isSuccess()));
                TransactionsAdapter transactionsAdapter=new   
            TransactionsAdapter((ArrayList<Transactions>)response.body());
                list.setAdapter(transactionsAdapter);


            }
        }
```

I already have 2 spinner on which users can choose month and year and they are declared as 2 integers: month and year.
Now i need to pass those values to Networksdk so that it show data only for that month and year.

I tried to remove 4 and 2016 from

```
public void getTransactions(Callback<List<Transactions>>callback){
    Call<List<Transactions>>call = 
BaseClient.getService().getTransactions(4,2016);
            call.enqueue(callback);
}
```

but it show error. Also I tried just to put

```
BaseClient.getService().getTransactions(int,int)
```

but it's not working?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `@Query` you can't use primitive types.

change

```
@GET("/api/UserPurchaseReports")
Call<List<Transactions>>getTransactions(
        @Query("mounthNumber")int month,
        @Query("yearNumber")int year
);
```

to

```
@GET("/api/UserPurchaseReports")
Call<List<Transactions>>getTransactions(
        @Query("mounthNumber")Integer month,
        @Query("yearNumber")Integer year
);
```

Comment: I changed that but how can i retrieve month and year from fragment here is the problem etTransactions(Callback<List<Transactions>>callback){
        Call<List<Transactions>>call = BaseClient.getService().getTransactions(4,2016);
                call.enqueue(callback);
    }
in NetworkSDK and if i remove 4,2016 or simply set int,int or integer,integer it report error because it need some int value. I want that value to be sent from fragment that i posted aboveBasicly user select year and month and spinner and that integers need to be sent to networksdk so I can retrieve list from that date

Comment: if you set `Integer` as parameter, you shouldn't have any problem. The Auto-boxing/unboxing functionality takes care of the conversion]

Comment: [link](http://pokit.org/get/?5a12509dafe3fc82925c2edbd938a89f.jpg) What do I need to inter in that () ? I have problem with it I tried with int int and Integer Integer It report error each time

Comment: you need to provide the parameters. two numbers.

Comment: Yea I realise that but I can't put 2 numbers there cuz I want to retrieve that numbers from another fragment where user will select it and pass it to this request

Comment: that's another problem (an easy and common one). Try to figure it out. If you are not able to do so, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472601/how-to-send-integers-from-fragment-to-retrofit-network-call) I opened a new question regarding that params issue